# Retriving data from form params is not possible in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller

In My Ruby on Rails Application

```
in my controller i have two action methods,first one is for load data and second one for saving data.
```

at first i wrote two different views for both action methods as follows

```
def index
-------
end
```

and corresponding view as follows..

```
<%= form_tag :action=>:save do %>
 -------
  <%= text_field_tag  templateitem.name %>
   ------
 ------
<%= submit_tag "save"%>
<%end%>
```

like above it consists some input items like radiobutton, checkbox ..etc

The other action method as follows ,in this all data read from view and saved into database

```
def save

--here i read the parameter values as follows 

 templateItem.value=params[templateItem.name]

end
```

then i wrote a view for saved data its works fine.

but my requirement is the saved data load in same index page for that i included all the code i written in save view is included in index page then the save action method is changed as follows

```
 def save

--here i read the parameter values as follows 

 templateItem.value=params[templateItem.name]
 --- saved into database

 return  redirect_to :action => 'index',:encounterid=>1 

end
```

then its not worked , i found the problem here is there is no data reading from view but it redirects to next view as i mentioned above action method, i didn't find solution for this problem  please help me to solve this..

Comment: You should go through the documentation of [ActionView::Helper::FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and REST API.

Answer (score 0):

params are only passed. After redirecting they are destroyed. So they are not accessible in your index action

Comment: if call save view then param values are retrieved ,if i call redirect the page then param values are not retrieved. my problem is how can i read those inputs for redirecting.

Comment: You can pass params in redirect_to
redirect_to :controller => 'blah blah', :action => 'index, :param1 => 'blah blah', :param2 => 'something'